# Why do I constantly have missing package dependencies?

Tags: software-installation, apt, packages

Many tries. Many half-fails.
All of the package managers that I'm using (apt-get, synaptic) always cannot really finish installations or removals. Just minutes ago I was trying to purge the [code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) package and IDE, the process didn't complete with multiple dependency errors:

Stuff about missing JDK and JRE

DPKG errors

And yet, I am completely certain that I have not deleted any of these packages, though I have a right to think again, because these problems seem to have started when I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Here is the complete output of my failed purging of code::blocks:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get purge codeblocks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  codeblocks-common libcodeblocks0 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  codeblocks*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 6,402 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 195481 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing codeblocks (16.01+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20170531+nmu1) ...
Error: missing `server' JVM at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf depends on ca-certificates-java; however:
  Package ca-certificates-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u151-b12-1~deb9u1); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jdk:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jdk:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jdk-headless (= 8u151-b12-1~deb9u1); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jdk:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u151-b12-1~deb9u1); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jdk:
 default-jdk depends on openjdk-8-jdk; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jdk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre-headless:
 default-jre-headless depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jre-headless (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jdk-headless:
 default-jdk-headless depends on default-jre-headless (= 2:1.8-58+b2); however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
 default-jdk-headless depends on openjdk-8-jdk-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jdk-headless (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-netx:armhf:
 icedtea-netx:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package icedtea-netx:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-8-plugin:armhf:
 icedtea-8-plugin:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.
 icedtea-8-plugin:armhf depends on icedtea-netx (= 1.6.2-3.1); however:
  Package icedtea-netx:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package icedtea-8-plugin:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre:
 default-jre depends on default-jre-headless (= 2:1.8-58+b2); however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
 default-jre depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-java-plugin:
 default-java-plugin depends on default-jre (= 2:1.8-58+b2); however:
  Package default-jre is not configured yet.
 default-java-plugin depends on icedtea-8-plugin; however:
  Package icedtea-8-plugin:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-java-plugin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf
 openjdk-8-jdk-headless:armhf
 openjdk-8-jdk:armhf
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf
 default-jdk
 default-jre-headless
 default-jdk-headless
 icedtea-netx:armhf
 icedtea-8-plugin:armhf
 default-jre
 default-java-plugin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So what exactly am I supposed to do to fix these problems? I have tried running `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` but apt-get said that the package didn't exist.

How do I fix these dependencies then?

How do you "configure" the packages?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the /etc/apt/sources.list ? This is in order to verify the sources used by apt in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The repo may not have the most up-to-date version of jdk or may be broken somehow.  Check out this link and download that tells you how to download and [install jdk 8 for raspberry pi](http://www.rpiblog.com/2014/03/installing-oracle-jdk-8-on-raspberry-pi.html).

[Here is a post from the Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=197824) that has some additional info on adding some symbolic links.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

If you are always having problems you are probably always doing something wrong.  Are you downloading packages from non-standard or non-Raspbian repositories?

Comment: I am downloading packages from standard package repositories. Is Code::Blocks a non-standard package? This problem has been going on for all package and remove operations.

Comment: Oh, btw, your command of 'sudo apt-get -f install' didn't work. It didn't fix any of my DPKG problems